# What characters will comprise a carriage return in an html textarea?

Tags: html

For example on my PC it looks like it will use "\r\n"? Could it ever be something different than that?

Comment: Are you asking this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324167/do-browsers-send-r-n-or-n-or-does-it-depend-on-the-browser

Comment: @thirtydot It seems so and still no good/definitive answer. the regexp is still a rn|n||r combo.

Comment: @thirtydot - actually, I don't think it is the same question. The question you link to is about the line ending encoding over the wire. This link http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1 states that if the data is sent as application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data, the line ending must be CR,LF. This question is about behaviour inside a textarea. From some recent experience I got the impression that some browsers weren't fussy, and would simultaneously treat CR,LF and bare LF's (possibly bare CRs too) as line endings.

Comment: @Alohci: It looks like you're right. I wasn't sure, so *I* didn't cast a close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically it's `\r\n` on Windows, `\r` on Mac and `\n` on *nix. If you take these into consideration you 're golden.

Also: I don't know if this is relevant in your case, but typically many programming languages define a string constant which represents the "native" form of end-of-line for the system they are running on (e.g. `PHP_EOL` in PHP, `Environtment.Newline` in C#, etc).

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon the OS I guess, the same old story:

- `\n` for unix like (and I think OS X too)
- `\r\n` for windows like
- `\r` old Apple OSes

Comment: That's only for how the OS (or more accurately, the default runtime libraries). The HTML spec specifies what a line ending should be (\r\n).