# Odd behavior for replacing newlines in PHP

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I've encountered some strange behavior with PHP. I have a string of text from a `<textarea/>` input and it seems that:

```
$text = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), null, $text);
```

successfully removes the newlines, whereas

```
$text = str_replace("\n", " ", $text)
$text = str_replace("\r\n", " ", $text)
$text = str_replace("\r", " ", $text)
```

**EDIT: the three str_replace calls above are for \n, \r\n, and \r**

does NOT successfully remove newlines. I even tried adding:

```
$text = str_replace(PHP_EOL, " ", $text);
```

but it doesn't fix the problem. I know I'm replacing the newlines with a space instead of null, but I would expect this to also work. After doing the 3-4 str_replace() calls, if I:

```
echo nl2br($text);
```

it does in fact find some remaining newline characters.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a line repeated 3 times... did you mean `\r\n` in the first one, `\r` in the second one and \n in the `3rd` one?

Comment: Also, you are replacing with `null` in the first method, but with a single space in the others. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Frank, yes it's a huge typo, sorry! jb, yes that is intentional, but I would expect each to behave similarly in actually removing the newlines.

Answer (score 3):

Text coming from an textarea **ALWAYS** has `\r\n` linebreaks.

So you should just do `$text = str_replace("\r\n", '', $text);`

See [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-textarea-element) for more info.

Comment: `Text coming from an textarea ALWAYS has \r\n linebreaks` - Is that true? I'd always assumed it used the type of line ending used by the OS... Well, you learn something every day. And passing `null` as the replacement is identical to passing `''`, so you might as well just do that.

Comment: Lemme get the spec for you. 1 sec pls

Comment: @DaveRandom Never too old to learn ;) And it was by no means trouble

Comment: If text in the textarea was not standardized, it would follow the OS conventions of the *user's* computer, not of the server.

Comment: Given the edit I made above (huge typo, sorry everyone!), $text = str_replace("\r\n", '', $text); didn't actually work.

Comment: Extremely relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324167/do-browsers-send-r-n-or-n-or-does-it-depend-on-the-browser

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
$text = str_replace("\r\n", " ", $text)
$text = str_replace("\r", " ", $text)
$text = str_replace("\n", " ", $text)
```

or

```
$text = str_replace("\r\n", null, $text)
$text = str_replace("\r", null, $text)
$text = str_replace("\n", null, $text)
```