# PHP Accept line breaks using REGEX

Tags: php

I want to allow line breaks from a text area input in this regex but they are being removed?

```
$n= ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9[:blank:][:space:]&.\n\r\\/+-]+", "", $_REQUEST['input']);
```

Comment: [`ereg_replace` is deprecated.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php)

Comment: ok then the preg_replace equivalent

Comment: @user1209203 `\n\r` is playing role there. Just remove them from your regex.

Comment: I added them to try and fix it, it's the same issue without them

Comment: Actually Rikesh you are are, the problem was I was looking only for \n but each new line seems to be \r\n is that always the case for all browsers?

Comment: I don't know of any OS which uses `\n\r` anywhere.

Comment: Ok and no cases of \n or \r on it's own?

Comment: @user1209203 [The spec states the linebreaks in textarea's should always be `\r\n`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10128541/508666)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `/m` modifier for your regex.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

> #### m (PCRE_MULTILINE)
>
> By default, PCRE treats the subject string as consisting of a single "line" of characters (even if it actually contains several newlines). The "start of line" metacharacter (^) matches only at the start of the string, while the "end of line" metacharacter ($) matches only at the end of the string, or before a terminating newline (unless D modifier is set). This is the same as Perl. When this modifier is set, the "start of line" and "end of line" constructs match immediately following or immediately before any newline in the subject string, respectively, as well as at the very start and end. This is equivalent to Perl's /m modifier. If there are no "\n" characters in a subject string, or no occurrences of ^ or $ in a pattern, setting this modifier has no effect.

Comment: Isn't `\s` *any whitespace character* and `\S` *any character that is not whitespace*? It would seem that the combination would match every possible character.