# When I return database data to TEXTAREA field the line breaks are gone

Tags: jquery, html, forms, textarea

So I'm ajax storing mulit line information from a TEXTAREA html field into a MySQL TEXT column.

When I recover the Data and insert it back into the TEXTAREA it comes back as one single line.

I'm using JQUERY with a simple

```
    $(document).on('blur','.updateblur ',function(event){
  //var whichstory = $(this).parent().find("input").attr('name');
  console.log($(this).val());
  var command = $(this).attr("id") ;
  var value = $(this).val() ;
            $.post('admin/storycontrol/'+whichstory+'/'+command+'/'+value+'/', function(data){
                console.log(data);
          });    
});
```

So in the text area I have

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

I store it in the database

Return it from Jquery

and it appears in the textarea as:

```
Line 1 Line 2
```

I would like it to appear back in the text area as once I stored it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to substitute in carriage returns for line breaks.

Replace all the line breaks with `\r\n`s to paste in your `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the text along with `&#013;&#010;` (ascii codes for cr,lf)

```
<textarea>
    hello &#013;&#010; world
</textarea>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ypmecjut/1/

Comment: Is this platform agnostic when it comes to web browsers?

Comment: I don't think so. the ascii codes should behave the same way for all the browsers. atleast the new ones.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear...On a mac is the textarea using a \n and on a windows a \r\n ?

Comment: I hope this would answer your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324167/do-browsers-send-r-n-or-n-or-does-it-depend-on-the-browser